# UINavigationBar shadowImage doesn't work with a dynamic image (dark mode)

Tags: ios, ios-darkmode

I'm trying to configure a dynamic image for `shadowImage` using an image from Assets catalog:

```swift
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "test") // image is configured for dark/light appearance
```

but it doesn't work, only a **light** image displayed in both themes. 
The same behavior I can see for `backgroundImage`.

Is there a workaround for my problem? Or have I just missed something in the implementation?